# What is the name of this view and how do i implement it in my android app

Tags: java, android

Hi coders what is the name of the view like the one on the picture below i tried to surf the web searching for words like android bottom drawer etc i couldnt find anything helpful
Please help me i need to inflate a layout into a view like that one [image: This view like the one found in whatsapp call]

Comment: This is BottomSheet. You can go through here 
[1]https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom#anatomy
[2]https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

Comment: Thank you so much i real appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

A [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment) is very close to this. It's a card that animates up from the bottom of the screen and can be opened or closed with a swipe gesture.

Comment: Thank you atleast now search for how to implement BottomSheetDialogFragment